# Getting values of <td> in the same <tr> of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated table which has rows of checkboxes as well as some other data. On a button click, I wanted to get the values of all the checked checkboxes. I managed to get this to work. I now want to get the texts of another `<td>` in the same `<tr>` and append that to a `<span>`.

I have tried the following:

**HTML**

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="23" class="inpcheckbox"></td><td class="fname">John</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="25" class="inpcheckbox"></td><td class="fname">Bob</td></tr>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#btnaddstudentstograde").click(function(){
    var studentids = $("#tblstudents input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
      var listo = $(this).closest("tr").find(".fname").text();
      $("#spanlist").append(listo);
    }).get();

$("#inpstudentids").val(studentids);

})
```

Comment: Nothing after `return` in a function will execute. Change the order

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. Thank you so much :)